# visual studio is not supporting python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My visual studio and python was working fine everything was going smoothly I just download a XAMPP  after downloading it my vs studio is not recognizing python I delete this software and vs studio and python, download it again but it is again giving the same error can be seen from figure attach. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htgVS.png)

Comment: what's the python interpreter display on the status bar at the bottom left in the VSCode? and when you click it, could you get the python interpreters list that you have installed on your PC?

Comment: it's not showing any interpreter at the bottom left corner when I click on it takes the search bar. there is no option for interpreters in search bar. I also tried to give path of python executable but it's not working

Comment: Thanks for your response, and could you attach some screenshots of it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed python extention? Go to "Extentons" on the left side of screen, enter Python and install the first extention. If need - restart vscode. Should work